# Opening an umbrella indoors

Tags: technology, superstition, hukot-hagoyim

Is there anything wrong with opening up an umbrella indoors according to Jewish tradition?

I have met many people who view it as bad luck or possibly rude.

On the other hand we are commanded not to follow the ways of the Emorites *([Darchei Emori](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99))*, which might apply to taking this kind of 'bad omen' seriously.

Comment: I've heard of it, but I'm 100% sure there is no source.

Comment: The Brisker Rav has a t'shuva somewhere about an umbrella in a succah (is it an ohel or not), which implies that opening an umbrella indoors is not intrinsically a problem (unless a succah is different than in a house somehow).

Comment: I was going to answer, it's bad luck to break shabbat by opening an umbrella :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [Rabbi Aviner](http://www.ravaviner.com/2011/12/shut-sms-140.html) this is superstition and may be done.

> Opening Umbrella Inside Q: Is it unlucky to open an umbrella inside A:
>   Superstition. (but not to be done on Shabbat, as an umbrella is
>   Muktzeh)

Comment: +1. But I thought you can't open it _Shabas_ because of _m'lacha_....

Comment: @msh210, But because it is a *m'lacha* to open an umbrella, it is therefore already *muktze* to even pick it up.

Comment: @jake, I agree, but saying "not to be [opened indoors] on Shabbat, as an umbrella is Muktzeh" would seem to minimize the _isur_ of opening an umbrella. (Can you open it _l'tzorech gufo_ then?)

Comment: Then would it be **forbidden** to give credence to this kind of superstition, say by closing an umbrella to escape the 'bad luck'?